# Nuxeo - Create Domain

Tags: java, nuxeo

I am newer to nuxeo. I had integrated my Java Application with Nuxeo. But now I want to perform the operations using Java in Nuxeo. I am not able to find any way to create a Domain in Nuxeo using Java Code. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: please share what you've already tried so far.

Comment: I had created a HttpAutomationSession using secret and userEmail. Now I want to create a domain using Java Code. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi After all research from my side, I got the below code to Create a Domain in Nuxeo using Java Automation Client :

```
Document companyDomain = null;
        try {
            companyDomain = (Document) session.newRequest(DocumentService.CreateDocument)
                    .setInput(NuxeoUtil.getRootDocument(session))
                    .set(NuxeoConstants.NUXEO_TYPE, NuxeoConstants.NUXEO_DOMAIN)
                    .set(NuxeoConstants.NUXEO_NAME, domainName)
                    .set(NuxeoConstants.NUXEO_PROPERTIES,
                            NuxeoConstants.NUXEO_TITLE + domainName + NuxeoConstants.NUXEO_DESCRIPTION + domainName)
                    .execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.error(e);
        }
```